# Query for a time interval using Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this:

```
                  id                  |          created_at
--------------------------------------+-------------------------------
 50d55ed2-d238-46dc-a9e4-f686d727f592 | 2021-04-27 04:16:18.744207+00
 73a6cec8-6747-4713-b5d2-a098e6b022a6 | 2021-04-27 04:17:17.159264+00
 a43a5f78-a30a-4597-a571-22b4bd94d71a | 2021-04-27 04:18:38.657008+00
 d822ce7e-e02a-4242-8502-f0d8f5c68819 | 2021-04-27 04:20:05.74405+00
 3312f868-39c8-414a-8173-68a7105ebefa | 2021-04-27 04:22:38.312941+00
 7980d464-e0d6-4697-9985-c57dff863fb6 | 2021-04-27 04:24:36.473433+00
```

I want to find all the records that have created_at at around the time `d822ce7e-e02a-4242-8502-f0d8f5c68819` was created (or, more than one id). My Postgres query is like this:

```
SELECT id, created_at FROM sometable1
WHERE created_at BETWEEN (
  SELECT created_at - INTERVAL '2 min' as after from sometable1 WHERE id IN ('d822ce7e-e02a-4242-8502-f0d8f5c68819')
) AND (
SELECT created_at + INTERVAL '2 min' as after from sometable1 WHERE id IN ('d822ce7e-e02a-4242-8502-f0d8f5c68819')
);
```

The result:

```
                  id                  |          created_at
--------------------------------------+-------------------------------
 a43a5f78-a30a-4597-a571-22b4bd94d71a | 2021-04-27 04:18:38.657008+00
 d822ce7e-e02a-4242-8502-f0d8f5c68819 | 2021-04-27 04:20:05.74405+00
```

Is it kind of silly to use two select statement? Is there a more concise method?

Comment: Your query won't work for more than one id! As you said "d822ce7e-e02a-4242-8502-f0d8f5c68819 was created (or, more than one id)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CTE as well

```
WITH prms AS (
    SELECT created_at - INTERVAL '2 min' as s ,
           created_at + INTERVAL '2 min' as e 
    FROM sometable1 
    WHERE id IN ('d822ce7e-e02a-4242-8502-f0d8f5c68819')
) 
SELECT id, created_at 
FROM sometable1 t
CROSS JOIN prms
WHERE t.created_at BETWEEN prms.s AND prms.e;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could phrase as saying that the absolute difference between the `created_at` value and the particular record's value is 2 minutes or less:

```sql
SELECT id, created_at
FROM sometable1
WHERE ABS(EXTRACT(epoch FROM (
          created_at -
          (SELECT created_at
           FROM sometable1
           WHERE id = 'd822ce7e-e02a-4242-8502-f0d8f5c68819')))::integer / 60.0) <= 2;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: Wow that's a lot of stuffs I can't parse with my eye. For example the "-" in there. SQL is so difficult. Interestingly this seems to be grabbing 4 records, "73a6cec8-6747-4713-b5d2-a098e6b022a6" to "3312f868-39c8-414a-8173-68a7105ebefa".

Comment: @huggie Sorry, I needed to divide by `60.0` to ensure that the quotient is a float.  What was happening is that anything within 2.99 days was getting returned.  Please check the demo to see that the answer has been fixed.

Comment: I'm still debating which query, your original one, the accepted answer, or mine, is ugliest.  In defense of SQL, the code usually looks a whole lot better than this.  Your requirement involves some fairly low-level manipulation of timestamps, hence the verbosity.

Comment: Is there an easy resource to learn SQL at your level? I struggle with it quite a lot. And documentation is usually too terse or dense for me.

Comment: You won't believe this, but I got good at SQL via answering Stack Overflow questions (and, to a _much_ lesser extent, using that knowledge in my coding and engineering jobs).  It's really like learning how to speak any other language: you need a lot of practice.  Doesn't help much that most software engineers only ever dabble in SQL reporting...

Comment: I totally laughed out loud in the office, especially at the last sentence. I guess there is no easy hack to learning this. Thanks for everything. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             count(*) filter (where id in ('d822ce7e-e02a-4242-8502-f0d8f5c68819') over
                  (order by created_at
                   range between interval '2 minute' preceding and interval '2 minute' following
                  ) as cnt_id
      from t
     ) t
where cnt_id > 0;
```

It would be interesting to compare the performance of this to other methods (that use subqueries or joins).  Usually, window functions have better performance.